# How to filter a groupby dataframe based on their values count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a groupby dataframe and I would like to return the top **3** groups with the highest value count.

for e.g the below dataframe expected output table should be `group` **20,30 and 33**

I wanted to display a raw dataset table, but the group function was not properly displayed on SO, That was I uploaded an image.

```
                     amount         cosine_group
cosine_group            

0                   952.5              0
4                   3000.0             4    
20                  2000.0            20
                    2000.0            20
                    2000.0            20
27                  2000.0            27    

30                  2100.0            30
                    2100.0            30
                    2100.0            30
33                  1065.0            33
                    1065.0            33
                    1065.0            33
                    1065.0            33
```

Expected Output:

```
                     amount         cosine_group
cosine_group            

20                  2000.0            20
                    2000.0            20
                    2000.0            20

30                  2100.0            30
                    2100.0            30
                    2100.0            30
33                  1065.0            33
                    1065.0            33
                    1065.0            33
                    1065.0            33
```

[image]

Comment: What code and results do you have so far?

Comment: Pleae provide an [mre], especially copyable input data and expected output as reference.

Comment: @Andreas I just updated the Question with the input and expected output

Comment: @JanWilamowski I just updated the question with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be very pythonic but definitely gets the work done.

```py
# retieve the index of the value counts
cosine_group_value = df["cosine_group"].value_counts().index

# get the fist 3 values  from the value counts (highest 3 values)
top3 = list(cosine_group_value)[:3]

# filter your dataframe using the top 3 values on the cosine_group column
df = df[df["cosine_group"].isin(top3)]
```

Comment: this returns index 27,30,33 . the expected output is index(20,30,33)

Comment: I just understood your question. Try the above solution and let me know

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie did you try it ?

Comment: yes I did and It gave me right answer. But how do I get the last value from  each output?  

Like `df.tail(1)` or `df.head(1)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.nlargest(3)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) to select the 3 largest size. Use `.isin()` to match for those rows with these values. Finally, use `.loc` to return the rows in original dataframe of the largest elements, as follows:

```
df = df.rename_axis(index='cosine_group0')   # to rename index axis name
df.loc[df['cosine_group'].isin(df.groupby('cosine_group', as_index=False)['cosine_group'].size().nlargest(3, 'size')['cosine_group'].tolist())]
```

Or use:

```
df = df.rename_axis(index='cosine_group0')   # to rename index axis
df.loc[df["cosine_group"].isin(df["cosine_group"].value_counts().nlargest(3).index)]
```

---

Comment: Definitely more pythonic than my proposed solution :)

Comment: I don't think that this is what the author requested, because he wants to filter a groupby dataframe, not a normal one.

Comment: @SeaBean the above function return just the last index 33 . I need the top 3 largest group from the dataframe 20, 30, 33

Comment: @SeaBean the above function return just the last index 33 . I need the top 3 largest group from the dataframe 20, 30, 33

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie  See my edit above.  Amended to show the 3 largest groups instead of elements.

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie  Want to clarify with you why `20` is selected instead of `27` ?  So it is the count that matter rather than value, right ?

Comment: @SeaBean Yes it is the count

The above expression leads to 

`ValueError: 'cosine_group' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.`

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie  I see, let me amend it.  You can solve the error by doing `df = df.rename_axis(index=None)`

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie  See my edit above.  Now used the `count` instead of max value.